# How can I make this swap more general purpose?

Tags: java, arrays, swap

[image: arrSwap]

So, I have this array of 4 elements and have to swap the values (See image). The first index should go to the second one and the second to third one and so forth. Now, I did something like the following in Java:

```
public class ArrSwap

private static Scanner SC= new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arr= new int[4];
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(String.format("Enter %d number: ",i+1));
        arr[i]= SC.nextInt();
    }

    int temp= 0;

    for(int j= 0;j<3;j++){
        for(int i= 0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
            temp= arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1]= arr[i];
            arr[i]= temp;
        }
    }

    for(int x: arr) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Now, I know it's not very intuitive :3 but that's the best I could come up with at the time. Now, how do I make this more general purpose? How do I improve it? And what's the logic that goes behind this sort of sorting?

Comment: Please visit https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this as this is not an actual code problem.

Comment: Tip: save the last value to a temp variable, then loop from `array.length-1` to `1`, assigning `array[i-1]` to `array[i]` . Then assign `temp` to `array[0]`.

Comment: How would you do this if the array were a row of bins, each containing a printed card? I for one would start by swapping the first and last and working my way inward, stopping at the middle. How can you realize that in code?

Comment: Check out `Collections.rotate(list, shift)` for a general purpose implementation of what you are trying to achieve. Your example would become: `List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(50, 60, 70, 80); Collections.rotate(nums, 1);`

Comment: @hoefling Although your method is useful, I am not sure how helpful would it be for a beginner (assumption) who wants to learn programming/Java

Comment: @koulini it's very helpful for a beginner once he starts to write unit tests for his own impl. Plus, knowing the standard library is always an advantage.